# Converting ASND resource (from ancient Mac app) to...anything playable

Tags: audio, converters

I have a number of old ASND "resources" pulled from an ancient (discontinued/abandoned) macOS (68K) app; I think I used resEdit some years ago to do this. Audacity is unable to do anything with them; I even tried importing as raw data.

I *believe* these were created with Adobe Soundbooth. If anyone knows of an app that can convert these ASND resource files to MP3 or anything playable today, I'd appreciate advice. I'd be more than happy to eMail or post some of these files if you'd like to try this with Soundbooth or Audition. Obviously, I do not own those apps; otherwise, I'd try it myself.

Thanks very much.
Barry

Edit: The app was created using World Builder (if that's any help).

Comment: Sadly SO isn’t the best platform for this question. I’d personally recommend the Adobe forums as you are more likely to get a good response

Comment: That said, _allegedly_ you should be able to simply change the `.asnd` to `.zip` and simply unzip the contents

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Adobe forum; yeah, that's a better place for this question. The files are of resource "ASND" but do not have file extensions. I did try adding the ".zip" but that didn't work.